# XSS when tags are removed from input text

Tags: xss, sanitization

Is it possible to execute an XSS attack if all tags are removed from text? By tags meaning everything matching pattern "<...>" (regex: `/<.*?>/g`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//
```

Don't invent your own filters. Encode for the contexts as described in the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet.

Comment: Could you provide fiddle, I am unable to make this execute

Comment: ok I see you fixed "&lt;" to "<", yep this works ... followup question ... if all < and > are removed, is there some weaknesses?

Comment: It all depends on where data is output. If it's always put between tags, then escaping or removing all <> should work. However as explained in the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat sheet there are many different contexts, each requiring its own handling.

Comment: But the thing with following OWASP is that it changes and in my case limited functionality wins over support. So I can achieve what I need and I don't need to follow updates in browser behaviour. At least I need to do it less.